# Characterizing locally connected continua

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, locally-connected

I am looking for a reference to the proof of the following result:
Let $E\subseteq\mathbb C$ be a continuum. Then the following assertions are equivalent:

(1) $E$ is locally connected;

(2) (i)  each of the connected  components of $\mathbb C\setminus E$ has a locally
connected boundary and
(ii)  for any $\epsilon>0$ there are at most finitely many components of $\mathbb C\setminus E$ with diameter  bigger than $\epsilon$.

I did not find it in the topology monographs by Kuratowski, but may be I overlooked it? And who proved this for the first time? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is properly stated? The $\epsilon$ from $(2)$ does not play any role.

Comment: @Marcos thanks; the last 5 words were cut...

Comment: The fact that each of the connected components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$ has a locally connected boundary is called "Torhorst Theorem", see Whyburn G.: Topological Analysis, Princeton Univ. Press 1958, p.33. For the equivalence stated I found a reference to Whyburn G.: Analytic Topology, fourth edition, AMS Colloq. Publ. XXVIII, 1971, p.113. I don't have access to this book, so I cannot verify this reference.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Torhorst and https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309022.pdf.

Comment: Continuum = compact connected set?

Comment: @ Kritiker der Elche   yes (in the realm of metric spaces or more generally Hausdorff spaces). Sometimes one adds the assumption that the set has at least two points (to avoid singletons to be considered as continua).